# What is text syntax in ImageMagick

Tags: linux, shell, imagemagick

I use following code convert text to image

```
convert -size 1000x100 xc:transparent -pointsize 30 -draw "text 0,30 'Text'" /tmp/test.png
```

what is x, y means in text x, y 'string'?

Comment: It’s the position of the string to be written into the image. See the manual: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#draw

Comment: @Pekka웃 is it left bottom position? If my text has multilines, is there way to auto resize the image height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 `label:`**

You can either use `label:` which provides a canvas large enough to hold your text - notice I didn't provide a canvas size:

```
convert -background yellow label:"This is some\nmulti-line text\nwhich\nsurprisingly enough -\nspans multiple lines" image.png
```

[image]

**Method 2 `-annotate`**

Or, you can use `-annotate` to write onto an outsize canvas, then `-trim` the canvas back to the minimum afterwards:

```
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:blue -pointsize 30 -gravity northwest -annotate 0 'Text\nwith multiple\nlines.' -trim result.png
```

[image]

When using `-annotate`, be sure to specify `-gravity` so that it positions according to the bounding box of your text, because if you do not, it will position according to the baseline (bottom-left corner) of your text.

**Method 3 `caption:`**

Or, you can use `caption:` which will size the text to best fit the box you provide:

```
convert -background pink -fill white -size 400x100 caption:"Here is a bunch of text that will be sized to best fit the box as far as is possible" result.png
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the ImageMagick "-draw text x,y string" option, "x,y" is the position of the bottom* left of the text measured from the the top left of the image.  You can use the "-gravity" option to measure from other corners of the image, for example,

```
convert -size 1000x100 xc:transparent -pointsize 30 -draw "gravity southwest text 0,30 'Text'" ...
```

will place the lower left corner* of the text 30 pixels above the lower left corner of the image.

*strictly speaking, it's the left end of the baseline of the text; if there are symbols with descenders such as "g" or "y", those extend below the baseline.  Demonstrate that with "-text 0,0 goody" and you'll just see the descenders extending into the top of the image.

```
magick -size 500x100 xc:yellow -pointsize 90 \
       -draw "text 0,0 'goody 0,1'" \
       -draw "text 0,100 'goody 0,100'" text.png
```

produces

[image]