# Imagemagick Draw text, draws past the border of the image. How to fix?

Tags: python, image, imagemagick

When I use Imagemagick's draw function to write text it will write beyond the border of the image. For example if the image is 200px width and the text I need to write will take up 300px, it continues off the edge and the rest of the text isn't shown.

I checked the manual and didnt find anything on how to set some type of constraint for it to stay within. Any ideas?

Comment: You obviously need a smaller font then. What is the command you run?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known area which you want to put text in, you should probably use `caption:` and not specify a font size, then ImageMagick will use the largest font commensurate with that size:

```
convert -size 200x100 -background blue -fill white caption:"Here is some funky text." result.png
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39557083/2836621/).